# Is this true that the Russian economy was efficient during war II?

Tags: soviet-union, russia

> During the second world war (You remember, the one that America was
>   briefly involved in), the USSR’s “russian system” recovered from being
>   devastated by the advancing Germans, and using a 'communist approach',
>   out-produced any country up to that date, From scratch. Hyper
>   efficient. Beat the Germans, basically single-handed. *[Forum Posting](http://www.libertariansforum.com/cgi-bin/freedom/YaBB.pl?num=1435394101/40#47)*

That seems to be amazing given that communist system never produce anything efficiently as far as I know.

Comment: This is going to depend on what we mean by "efficient" and what we're counting being produced.

Comment: So very hard to answer isn't it?

Comment: Beat the Germans single handed?...?

Comment: I'm not sure why "russian system" and "communist approach" are in scarequotes.  The source is an opinion in an internet discussion forum devoted to a non-mainstream political view, and it provides no evidence. I'm sufficiently skeptical of the source that I think any reasoning arising from this source is suspect.

Comment: I think it is true to say that most economies work well in times of war. At least they tend to produce full-employment. It was not only the USSR that operated a 'command economy' during the second world war. Many countries did, including, of course Britain. Ernest Bevin, Britain's Minister of Labour and National Service had the power, under the Defence of the Realm Act to command anyone to work anywhere. Private businesses were requisitioned and millions of women conscripted into war service. Food rations were at times meagre but no one went without.

Comment: There are economic measures that are typically used for this sort of thing. Unfortunately, the numbers tend to be very hard to come by (and hard to trust) out of communist countries, but still they exist.

Comment: It is hard to say how efficient the Soviet economy was in WWII,  It is easy to see that it was very *effective* and massively outproduced the German economy by wide margins, which was no model of efficiency itself.

Comment: The USSR production was so very efficient in WWII that Stalin said in 1941: 'America is a nation of machines. Without those machines we will lose the war.'. The aid the USA gave to the USSR came from a nation that was truly efficient at production. To understand the massive scope of aid to Russia read 'Feeding the Bear: American Lend-Lease Aid to Russia in WWII' by Hubert P. van Tuyll

Comment: @user3847 The Lend-lease was the thing which was always exaggerated in USA and lessened in Soviet Union. The truth is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @user4419802: Lend-lease aid tp Russia was not an exaggerated 'thing'. It was hard production numbers thousands of Sherman tanks. tens of thousands of Studebaker trucks, millions and millions of rounds of ammunition of all calibers and food.. Do some research into the subject and then tell me that fatuous line: 'the truth lies somewhere in the middle'.

Comment: @user3847 First of all, the tins can't fight. Landing those shermans on the French shore in 1942 would have been of true significance, while sending them to Murmansk was not. Anyone has to realize simple things first.

Comment: @user4419802 Research, research, research! You believe Murmansk was the only port available to deliver US Lend-lease materiel. In fact there were 3 routes (Arctic, Persian and Pacific). Sherman tanks came via Persian route. You won't see Russian WWII film footage of Russian crews operating Sherman tanks since the fiction of Russian's self-sufficiency had  to be preserved. US-made airplanes (aerocobra) were flown via Arctic route (Alaska to Siberia),

Comment: @user3847 SU already had a better tank and produced almost as many T-34s as USA produced Shermans. Needless to say, tne part of Shermans imported in SU was about 1/10. The situation with airplanes was surely different (lack of materials, the necessity to design new competing models from scratch). That's the reason why Sherman is a rare guest in Soviet chronicles but Aerocobra is not.

Answer (score 15):

The quote contains a lot of hyperbole, I'm going to go over them briefly and then set them aside.

- "*the one that America was briefly involved in*" The US entered the war in December 1941, the USSR in June 1941. One could stretch the Soviet involvement back to the Winter War or the Invasion of Poland. Either way, both fought hard for years.
- "*From scratch*" Hardly. The Soviet Union was a [military and industrial powerhouse in the 1930s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Soviet_Union_%281927%E2%80%9353%29#Industrialization_in_practice). I address this in detail below.
- "*Beat the Germans, basically single-handed.*" This has some factual basis. The sheer scale of the Eastern Front dwarfed all others. Nine of every ten German soldiers died on the Eastern Front and by the time of D-Day Germany was already on the retreat. However, the other Allies were fighting the Germans in Africa, the Mediterranean, Scandinavia, and oceans while also fighting the Japanese and supplying the Soviets.

---

Yes, the wartime expansion and recovery of the USSR's production was nothing short of amazing, but so was the German and American.  They did it at a great cost of human suffering.

"Efficient" is a very slippery word. We don't know what that person meant. I'm going to stick to simple material numbers.  I also think the statement "from scratch" implies the person thinks the USSR was militarily and industrially backwards at the start of the war.  Let's address that first.

In the 1930s the Soviets were at the forefront of tactical thinking. They recognized the importance of the tank and the aircraft in achieving surprise and mobility. They used it to rapidly penetrate the enemy lines and cause havoc in their rear faster than the enemy could react. They called it [Deep Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_operation) and it was very similar to the Blitzkrieg tactics the Germans would use so successfully.

Unfortunately, the [Great Purges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Purge) of the late 30s killed or sent into exile over half of their officers, especially the most imaginative commanders.  They were left with the most unimaginative officers mostly concerned with politics. [Deep Battle was politically discredited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_operation#The_impact_of_the_purges) and the Soviet armored strength was dispersed.

The disastrous Winter War with Finland in 1939/40 exposed the woeful state of Soviet arms.  A victorious but humiliated Soviet Union began to, very slowly, return some of the previous military professionalism to their army, but not fast enough.

Meanwhile, the Soviets were developing some of the most advanced arms in the world.  The [T-34 medium tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-34), [KV-1 heavy tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kliment_Voroshilov_tank), [Yak-1 fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-1), and [IL-2 "flying tank"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-2) were all in production at the time of invasion.  They were all equal to or superior to the equivalent German units at the time.  They all stayed in production for the whole war.  Trouble is, there weren't nearly enough and they were incompetently used.

No, the Soviets did not rebuild "from scratch".

---

The Soviets were caught by surprise and off guard by [Operation Barbarossa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Barbarossa), after all they had been cooperating with the Germans for years and had [a non-aggression pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact).  In their rapid retreat they evacuated whole factories to safety beyond the Ural Mountains.  Conditions were brutal, but they set about cranking out war materials.

Part of the efficiency of Soviet production was their focus on a relatively small number of models.  For example, they had three tank hulls, the light [T-60/70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-70), the medium T-34 and the heavy KV.  They used them for everything with mixed success.  As tanks they were very successful with excellent armor and guns.  As vehicle hulls, the shortcomings of Soviet drive train designs became more apparent.

Once a factory began production it often continued to make that model even once better ones were available; it would take time and money to retool and retrain. Is this "efficient"? It certainly produced more stuff.

Let's look at the production numbers for medium and heavy tank hulls.  I've included America for comparison.  I've excluded 1945 because it is a partial year and Germany was collapsing.  Overconfidence caused American production to slow down in 1944.  The Americans did not believe in heavy tanks.

```
     | German         | Soviets        | American       |
     | Medium | Heavy | Medium | Heavy | Medium | Heavy |
1941 |  2700  |    0  |  2800  | 1350  |  1400  |   0   |
1942 |  4000  |   80  | 12500  | 2600  | 15500  |   0   |
1943 |  9000  |  650  | 17000  | 1450  | 28000  |  40   |
1944 | 15000  | 1050  | 16000  | 4750  | 15500  |   0   |
```

The Germans were outproduced, especially in heavy hulls.  However, after 1941 the Soviet factories were safe beyond the Urals and could produce unimpeded.  Meanwhile, Germany was under increasing Allied bombardment yet her production went up.  The Americans had a production boom of their own.

Another item of note is the [German population during WWII was 70 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Germany#/media/File:Population_of_German_territories_1800_-_2000.JPG), while the [Soviets had 200 million people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties_of_the_Soviet_Union#Total_population_losses), with [America at 130 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_United_States).  This gets a little more complicated once you consider German occupied territories and allies.

This is just one data point.  It ignores things like, for example, that the US was producing a two ocean navy, as well as a massive air force, and supplying material to the Soviets, all while keeping up a good lifestyle for its citizens.  My conclusion, based on this and further study of WWII, is that *all the major combatants performed industrial miracles during the war* but the US and the UK did it without severe hardship.  The Soviets and Germans under conditions of extreme hardship, but also using [forced labor and brutal conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Soviet_Union_%281927%E2%80%9353%29#Industrialization_in_practice).

References.

- [Wikipedia: German AFV Production During WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_armored_fighting_vehicle_production_during_World_War_II#Total_production)
- [Wikipedia: Soviet AFV Production During WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_combat_vehicle_production_during_World_War_II)

Comment: Not to put too find a point on it, but if one stretches the Soviet involvement to WWII to the Winter War or the Invasion of Poland, then it's worth pointing out that the Soviets began the war fighting *on the Nazi side* and only switched later...

Comment: That bit about the 2-ocean navy is kind of important. If Churchill is to be believed, the armor used for tanks (particularly heavy ones I'd wager), competes directly with the armor needed for warships. If you want to compare overall productive capacity, you really need to take that into account.

Comment: Good answer, but you should also mention Land-Lease which made the surge in production possible. Much of Soviet production relied heavily on equipment supplied by USA. Even some of sheet steel was shipper from USA. The legendary Katyusha artillery was mounted on Studebaker trucks. Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg In Winter War Soviet Union fought _against_ german ally (Finland).

Comment: @Michael I don't have the references to work out the impact of Lend-Lease on the Soviet economy. That's enough material for its own question.

Comment: @user4419802 At the time Finland was neutral, they allied with Germany during the later Continuation War. Doesn't much matter because the point is the Soviets were involved in fighting before Barbarossa, though not total war.

Comment: It's a common mistake saying that Soviet Union was caught by surprise in 1941. All the preparations were held in time. The problem was that Red Army was totally helpless against "new" war strategies and tactics of Germany.

Comment: @user4419802 I believe they were caught off guard *and* they were helpless against the new strategies. That's a topic for a whole other question.

Comment: @Schwern All the big players were in long before 1941, except USA.

Comment: @Schwern There are too many Soviet documents on military defensive preparations in June 1941. The armies are not the needles, and never were.

Comment: @user4419802 Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interim_Peace#The_Molotov-Ribbentrop_Pact_and_the_Winter_War and see for yourself who was Germany's closest ally at the time....

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Hitler simply betrayed his allies. It doesn't change that Finland and Baltic states were de facto allied with Germany in 1939.

Comment: Excellent answer, but one thing missing from the analysis is the methods for achieving productivity. E.g. the fact that Soviet workers were insanely more productive, among other things, because the alternative to poor work wasn't - as it was in US - "bad report from a supervisor" in best case and "being fired" at worst - it was "being sent to the front to die" at best and "being shot as saboteur and your family sent to labour camp as family of enemy of the state" at worst. Nothing concentrates the mind as wonderfully as the prospect of being hanged, to paraphrase.

Comment: @DVK I need a citation that Soviet workers were "insanely more productive", the production numbers I posted say otherwise per capita. Also a citation that harsh working conditions resulted in better productivity. While it *may* have caused more units to be produced, those units *may* have been of such low quality that they'd have been better off producing higher quality in lower numbers. Also, many Soviet factories continued producing obsolete weapons and equipment rather than retooling, is that efficient? I won't argue further in a comment thread, these would make good questions.

Comment: @Schwern - poor wording. I meant insanely more compared to what they would be under, say, Brezhnev 70s regime, not compared to Americans in WWII

Comment: ... meaning that productivity improvements of USSR during WWII was due to draconian Stalinist incentives, NOT due to  'communist approach' as the OP's quote stated.